# How to handle Confirm() of Javascript as per my following requirements?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

My Requirement is this.
Steps:-

1. On Client Click (button)
2. Disabled the Button.
3. Then it should prompt for OK or CANCEL.
4. If OK then fire the OnClick event (Code Behind).
5. If CANCEL then don't make a server-side trip and enable the button.

Following is the code I am using for the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;return Confirm();" Text="Testing"  runat="server" />
```

But instead of what I am expecting, it is disabling button and prompting Confirmation but if User hits Cancel then button stays as disabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to disable the button. user wont be able to do anything without clicking the buttons in the confirm box. Just use this.

```
 OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Submit?');"
```

Comment: +1, however I think the point of disabling the button is AFTER they click "OK" and the postback occurs, if it takes a few seconds for a response, I'm assuming he wants to prevent a double-postback.  Technically, they could click submit again, and click "OK" again before the response.

Comment: @Keith is right. Thats what is happening right now. Users click button more than once

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this as jQuery, so I would suggest using jQuery to define an event handler, separate from the `OnClientClick` property:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Testing" CssClass="confirm-button" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.confirm-button').click(function(event) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

<del>However, as [@Shoban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866825/how-to-handle-confirm-of-javascript-as-per-my-following-requirements/3866862#3866862) pointed out, there's no need to disable the button, since `confirm` is modal.</del> Since `confirm` is modal, there's only a need to disable to button after the `confirm` prompt has been addressed.  So, the logic would probably be cleaner if you only disabled the button if the response from `confirm` is `true`:

```
        $('.confirm-button').click(function(event) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am using Jquery as well in my code. But now problem is this asp:Button has onclick event associated with it. After client side confirmation -> when yes -> it is disabling button. This stops Browser's Submit request (post-back behavior), so button does not fire OnClick Event. What do you say here?

Comment: @Crawling The form submission is being disabled because my code is calling `event.preventDefault()`, not because it is enabled.  I've edited my answer to fix this (it was stopping the submit when "yes" was clicked on the confirm, instead of when "no" was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

try this in OnClientClick-

```
this.disabled=true;
var result = Confirm();
this.disabled = result;
return result;
```

**If your trying to disable postback on the button just call `return Confirm();`**

Answer (score 0):

Only disable the button if they click OK.

```
var customConfirm = function(){
  var proceed = confirm("are you sure");
  if(proceed){
    // disable button while server is posting back
  }
  return proceed;
}
```